# How can set Customer-Support perspective to my custom Employee in HYBRIS?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I created my custom group and employee who has this group. I did everything right and I want mine custom employee to use the same perspective he uses CustomerSupportAgent. So when login with my custom employee to see Customer-Support perspective, not the Administration perspective. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Backoffice perspective configuration is available at backoffice-config XML.
In case you need to make CS perspective available to your custom employee, Take a look at the example from customersupportbackoffice-backoffice-config.xml

```
<context component="perspective-chooser" principal="orgemployeerole" merge-by="module" parent="commerceservicesbackoffice">
    <y:perspective-chooser xmlns:y="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/perspectiveChooser">
        <y:defaultPerspective name="organizationBackofficePerspective"/>
        <y:authority name="orgemployeerole">
            <y:perspective id="organizationBackofficePerspective"/>
            <y:perspective id="CustomerSupport-Perspective"/>
        </y:authority>
    </y:perspective-chooser>
</context>

<context component="perspective-view-switcher" principal="customersupportadministratorrole">
    <vs:view-switcher xmlns:vs="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/viewSwitcher">
        <vs:authority name="customersupportadministratorrole">
            <vs:view id="CustomerSupport-Perspective"/>
            <vs:view id="hmc2"/>
        </vs:authority>
    </vs:view-switcher>
</context>
```

Or just assign `customersupportagentgroup` to your custom group if it's feasible.

```
UPDATE UserGroup; UID[unique = true]; groups(uid)[append = true]
; admingroup        ; customersupportagentgroup
```

Comment: How can I assign customersupportagentgroup to mine custom group?

Comment: The easiest way is to use impex. I've added an example to the answer. Don't forget to update UIDs.
Also just manage it  via backoffice `User -> User Groups`

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `CustomerSupportAgent` to your employee or make your group a sub-group of the same to view the CS perspective.

Comment: How can I do this? I'm new in hybris. Thank you